# Why use Pythong gettext for localization instead of a simple string table?

Tags: python, gettext

Why would you use gettext instead of a simple string table for localization?  A string table has numerous advantages (especially when you are already using a sqlite database in your app)

- Text to be translated is represented as a constant in code (eg - CONST_STRING_NO_DEVICE)
- Single location where all translations are contained
- No formatting limits - translated text can contain additional formatting parameters
- Languages can be changed dynamically, on the fly, with a simple database requery